# windows command prompt substring in a for loop

Tags: windows, command-line, substring

I have to say before I describe my problem that I am new in performing command line prompts  (Windows 10).

I have a directory with txt files (among other files). I need to perform a command line executable (txt2las) where the txt files are read and a .las file is written. This is what I have so far as a command prompt `for /R %f in (.\*.txt) do txt2las  -i %f -o %f.laz`

However, this creates files like name.txt.laz. What I want is name.laz, therefore somehow take the substring from beginning till the last four characters. Can someone help me how to do that?

I tried the substring "function" but does not write anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the just the name of the file (without the extension) by using the `~n` modifier:

```
for /R %f in (.\*.txt) do txt2las -i %f -o "%~dpnf.laz"
```

You can read more about the modifiers in the `FOR /?` help docs.

---

Edit per comments:

To ensure it is placed in the same directory as the source, add the `~dp` modifiers in addition to `~n`. This will extract the `d`rive and `p`ath in addition to the file `n`ame. Also, you will likely want to wrap this entire output in quotes in the event the path has spaces in it.

Comment: But this solution does not put the file in the original subfolder. Not that it matters 100% but would be better.

Comment: @StellaPsοm - by using the `~dpn` modifier you can do this. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
... do txt2las  -i %f -o %~nf.laz
```

The documentation can be read by executing `for /?` from the prompt.